# Why is RSpec 2.13.0 / Capybara 2.1.0 not able to fill_in a field by it's label text in this test in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, rspec2

First, this test has passed many times already.  I've been developing new features today, and for some reason, it now fails.

Here's the pertinent portion of my test spec:

```
    ...
    describe "when entering a valid prepay access code after signing in" do
        before do
            sign_in user, subdomain: 'bdsp'
            visit public_root_url(subdomain: 'bdsp')
            fill_in "code", with: job.code
            click_button "Continue"
        end

        it { should have_selector('h1', text: "My #{job.subject_label}s for #{job.name}") }

        describe "adding a sports prepay subject" do
            let(:submit) { "Add #{job.subject_label}" }
            before do
                puts page.html
                valid_create_player
            end

            it "should create a player" do
                expect { click_button submit }.to change(PrepaySubject, :count).by(1)
            end
    ...
```

Note how I'm calling `puts page.html` right before `valid_create_player` so I can verify the existence of the input/label I expect.

The pertinent part of my `spec\support\utilities.rb` file:

```
    def valid_create_player
        fill_in 'First name', with: "Foo"
        fill_in 'Last name', with: "Bar"
        fill_in 'Team',     with: "The Foobars"
        fill_in 'Coach',     with: "Bar Foo"
    end
```

And the results of my test (restricted to the single test for `should create a player`):

```
    Jims-Mac-mini:msc_rails4_staging jim$ rspec spec/requests/public_pages_spec.rb:103
    No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
    Run options: include {:locations=>{"./spec/requests/public_pages_spec.rb"=>[103]}}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>MSC - Staging App | Studio 2&#39;s MySmileCentral - Subjects</title>
            <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/public.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/jm30.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js"></script>
            <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/public.js"></script>
        <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/prepay_subjects.js"></script>

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body data-no-turbolink="true">
            <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <nav>
                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
                                <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                        Account <b class="caret"></b>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="/users/1">Profile</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/users/1/edit">Settings</a></li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a data-method="delete" href="/signout" rel="nofollow">Sign out</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

            <div class="container">

    <h1>My Players for Job Number 1</h1>

    <div class="medium center">
        <p><a id="order-instructions-show" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" 
            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Toggle ordering instructions</a></p>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
            <h4 style="text-align: left">1. Create a player record for each child being photographed.<br />2. Click the 'Order Pictures' link (next to each player) to make your selection.<br />&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <span style="font-size: 80%; line-height: 125%;">NOTE:  You can pay for all pictures for all of your players in ONE transaction!<br />&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Just click 'My Players' (above) to start ordering for another player.</span><br />3. After adding all the pictures you wish to order, proceed to viewing your cart (by clicking the 'Cart' link above) to complete your transaction.</h4>
        </div>
    </div>

            <h3>You have not added any players yet</h3>

        <div id="no-prepay-subjects-bkgd">
            <div class="well small center">
                <h1>Add a New Player</h1>
                <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/prepay_subjects" class="form-horizontal" id="new_prepay_subject" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>

    <fieldset>
        <input id="job_id" name="prepay_subject[job_id]" type="hidden" value="1" /> 
        <input id="public_user_id" name="prepay_subject[public_user_id]" type="hidden" value="1" />

        <div class="control-group">     
            <label class="control-label" for="prepay_subject_first_name">First name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="prepay_subject_first_name" name="prepay_subject[first_name]" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">     
            <label class="control-label" for="prepay_subject_last_name">Last name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="prepay_subject_last_name" name="prepay_subject[last_name]" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="prepay_subject_Team">Team</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="prepay_subject_team" name="prepay_subject[team]" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="prepay_subject_Coach">Coach</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="prepay_subject_coach" name="prepay_subject[coach]" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <table style="width: 400; margin-left: 100px;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left; width: 175px">
                        <input checked="checked" id="prepay_subject_buddy_false" name="prepay_subject[buddy]" type="radio" value="false" /> Individual/Team
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: left; width: 225px">
                        <input id="prepay_subject_buddy_true" name="prepay_subject[buddy]" type="radio" value="true" /> Buddy <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left; width: 175px"></td>
                    <td style="text-align: left; width: 225px">
                        <a href="http://assests0_bop_heroku_com.s3.amazonaws.com/images/jm30/whats_a_buddy_shot.png" onclick="window.open(this.href,&#39;create_company&#39;, &#39;height=580, width=630&#39;);return false;" title="Click here for more information about buddy photos">What&#39;s a buddy shot?</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <br />
        </table>
        <br />              
    </fieldset>
                    <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary pull-center" name="commit" type="submit" value="Add Player" />
    </form>     <div class="clearfix"></div><!-- keeps the submit button properly wrapped in 'well' div -->
            </div>
        </div>


                <footer>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/about">About</a></li> |
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li> |
                <li><a href="http://news.railstutorial.org/">News</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
            <div class="left text-left">
                    Studio 2<br />

                    Phone: 123-456-7890<br />

            </div>
            <div class="right text-right">
                    Copyright &copy 2015 Studio 2,<br />All Rights Reserved <br />

                        Sampletown, US
            </div>
    </footer>

            </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    F

    Failures:

        1) Public Pages public users home page when entering a valid prepay access code after signing in adding a sports prepay subject should create a player
             Failure/Error: valid_create_player
             Capybara::ElementNotFound:
                 Unable to find field "Team"
             # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:135:in `valid_create_player'
             # ./spec/requests/public_pages_spec.rb:100:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

    Finished in 2.85 seconds
    1 example, 1 failure

    Failed examples:

    rspec ./spec/requests/public_pages_spec.rb:103
```

I just don't understand how Capybara isn't finding the field for "Team" when it's label clearly says "Team" in the outputted html.  Especially since this worked before today - and worked many times.  All other tests that use `fill_in` by the label text still work.  Why does Capybara seem to be blind to my "Team" field?

Comment: I also know that I could simply change the `fill_in` to find the element by it's ID rather than by the label's text, but I'm not interested in a workaround.  I want Capybara to work as it's supposed to here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML ids are case sensitive and you've defined the `Team` label as applying to the id `prepay_subject_Team`, which does not appear in your page. Only the id `prepay_subject_team` exists (i.e. lower case `t` in `Team`).

If the capitalization in the `for` attribute of a label element doesn't match the capitalization of the `id` attribute of it's matching input element, Capybara can't find the input element.

Comment: According to the Capybara docs found [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions:fill_in), "The field can be found via its name, id or label text."  I've identified `Team` as the label text to find, which is clearly on the rendered page. My `utilities.rb` is full of capitalized field names, and every other spec in my suite passes.  Even the `First name` and `Last name` fields in _this_ test get filled in correctly, despite having input ids of `prepay_subject_first_name` and `prepay_subject_last_name`.  Very strange, IMO.

Comment: I just tried `fill_in 'team'`, and Capybara returned `Unable to find field "team"`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your capitalized label text. The problem is that the capitalization in the `for` attribute of your `label` item does not match the capitalization of the `id` attribute of your `input` item, so the label isn't "attached" to anything (i.e. there is no input field to find).